# Error STATUS 400 al Hacer una Petición POST Desde ANGULAR a un Backend en SPRING-BOOT

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http, postman

tengo una situación de la cual ya llevo semanas trabado y necesito sacar mi frustración de una vez por todas....

Tengo 3 Entidades desde Spring boot:

```
  * -  Caratula (Atributos) : {

private Long id;

private Date fecha;

private boolean tieneExpediente;

private String aclaracion;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_distribuidora")
private Distribuidora distribuidora

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_tipocaratula")
private TipoCaratula tipoCaratula;  (ESTE ES UN ENUM) 

private String tipoGravedad;         //LEVE - GRAVE

private String caratulaSeleccionada;  //  ES UNA CONCATENACION DE LOS ATRIBUTOS : 

tipoCaratula + tipoGravedad + aclaracion 

...CONSTRUCTORES, GETTERS, SETTERS.....

}

* - Expediente (Atributos) : {

    @Column(name="fecha")
    private Date fecha; 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_caratula")
    private Caratula caratulaSeleccionada;      

    @Column(name="nro_expediente")
    private int nroExpediente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_distribuidora")
    private Distribuidora distribuidora;

...CONSTRUCTORES, GETTERS, SETTERS.....
}




 * - TipoCaratula (Atributos) : {

private Long id;

private String tipoDeCaratula;

...GETTERS, SETTTERS, CONSTRUCTOR

}
```

Este es Mi Rest Controller de Caratula :

```
   @RestController
@RequestMapping("/caratula_rest/")
public class Caratula_Rest {
    
    @Autowired
    private Caratula_Service caratula_Service;
    
    @GetMapping
    private ResponseEntity<List<Caratula>> getAllCaratula(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(caratula_Service.findAll());
    }
    @PostMapping
    private ResponseEntity<Caratula> saveCarartula(@RequestBody Caratula caratula){
        try {
            Caratula caratulaGuardada = caratula_Service.save(caratula);
            return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/caratula_rest/"+caratulaGuardada.getId())).body(caratulaGuardada);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }
    @DeleteMapping (value = "delete/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<Boolean> deleteCaratula (@PathVariable ("id") Long id){
        caratula_Service.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(!(caratula_Service.findById(id)!=null));
    }
}
```

este es mi Rest Controller de Expediente :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/expediente_rest/")
public class Expediente_Rest {
    
    @Autowired
    private Expediente_Service expediente_Service;
        
    @GetMapping
    private ResponseEntity<List<Expediente>> getAllExpediente(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(expediente_Service.findAll());
    }
    @PostMapping("/save")
    private ResponseEntity<Expediente> saveExpediente(@RequestBody Expediente expediente){
        try {
            // Procesar y guardar el expediente recibido
            Expediente expedienteGuardado = expediente_Service.save(expediente);
            return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/expediente_rest/"+expedienteGuardado.getId())).body(expedienteGuardado);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(expediente); 
        }
    }   
    @DeleteMapping (value = "delete/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<Boolean> deleteExpediente (@PathVariable ("id") Long id){
        expediente_Service.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(!(expediente_Service.findById(id)!=null)); 
    }
}
```

AHORA.... EN ANGULAR ....

Este es mi Expediente.service.ts:

```
  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExpedienteService {
  
  private API_SERVER: string = "http://localhost:8080/expediente_rest/";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  public getAllExpediente():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.API_SERVER);
  }
  public saveExpediente(expediente: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.API_SERVER + "save", expediente);
  }
  public deleteExpediente(id:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.delete(this.API_SERVER + "delete/" + id);
  }
}
```

este es el HTML del componente Expediente:

```
<form [formGroup]="nuevoExpedienteForm" (submit)="guardarDatos()">
<mat-form-field style="width: 400px;">
    <mat-label>Ingrese fecha</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" id="fecha" formControlName="fecha">
    <mat-hint>
        <FONT style="color: rgb(93, 27, 192); font-size: small;">La fecha se acomodará luego de guardar el registro
        </FONT>
    </mat-hint>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field style="width: 400px;">
    <mat-label>Seleccione la Caratula:</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="caratulaSeleccionada" (selectionChange)="onChangeCaratulaSeleccionada()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of nuevaCaratula" [value]="item.caratulaSeleccionada">
            {{item.caratulaSeleccionada}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
    <input matInput formControlName="nroExpediente">
</mat-form-field>
```

Distribuidora

```
<br>
```

ESTE ES MI COMPONENTE DE TYPESCRIPT:

```
export class CargarNuevoExpedienteComponent {
      caratulaSeleccionada: any;
      distribuidora: any;
      nuevoExpedienteForm!: FormGroup;
      expedientes: Expediente[] = [];
      distribuidoras!: any;
      tiposCaratulas!: any;
      nuevaCaratula: any[] = [];
    
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public router: Router,
        private distribuidoraService: DistribuidoraService,
        private nuevaCaratulaService: NuevaCaratulaService,
        private expedienteService: ExpedienteService) {
      }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        const fechaActual = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
        this.nuevoExpedienteForm = this.fb.group({
          id: [''],
          fecha: [fechaActual, Validators.required],
          caratulaSeleccionada: [''],
          nroExpediente: ['', Validators.required],
          distribuidora: ['']
        });
        this.nuevoExpedienteForm.get('distribuidora')?.disable(); // Aquí deshabilitas el campo de formulario
    
        this.distribuidoraService.getAllDistribuidora().subscribe(resp => {
          this.distribuidoras = resp;
        });
    
        this.nuevaCaratulaService.getAllCaratula().subscribe(resp => {
          this.nuevaCaratula = resp;
    
        })
      }
    
      onChangeCaratulaSeleccionada() {
        const selectedCaratula = this.nuevoExpedienteForm.get('caratulaSeleccionada')?.value;
        this.caratulaSeleccionada = selectedCaratula;
        const selectedDistribuidora = this.nuevaCaratula.find((item: any) => item.caratulaSeleccionada === selectedCaratula)?.distribuidora.nombreDistribuidora;
        this.distribuidora = selectedDistribuidora;
        this.nuevoExpedienteForm.patchValue({
          distribuidora: selectedDistribuidora
        });
      }
    guardarDatos() {
        const selectedCaratulaId = this.nuevoExpedienteForm.get('caratulaSeleccionada')?.value.id;
        const selectedDistribuidoraId = this.nuevoExpedienteForm.get('distribuidora')?.value.id;
    
        const expedienteData = {
          fecha: this.nuevoExpedienteForm.get('fecha')?.value,
          nroExpediente: this.nuevoExpedienteForm.get('nroExpediente')?.value,
          caratulaSeleccionada: { id: selectedCaratulaId },
          distribuidora: { id: selectedDistribuidoraId }
        };
    
        this.expedienteService.saveExpediente(expedienteData).subscribe(
          resp => {
            this.expedientes.push(resp);
            // Realiza alguna acción adicional si es necesario después de guardar los datos correctamente
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);
            Swal.fire({
              title: 'Error al guardar los datos',
              text: 'Ha ocurrido un error al intentar guardar los datos. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde.',
              icon: 'error'
            });
          }
        );
      }
```

YO NECESITO MANDARLE UNA PETICIÓN POST A LA URL http://localhost:8080/expediente_rest/
La idea es que el usuario PRIMERO, llene un formulario para la carga de Caratula (ESO FUNCIONA), este formulario de Registro se guarda correctamente en mi BDD de POSTGRES..

este es un .sql de como se guardan los datos de Caratula en mi BDD:

COLUMNAS:
id, aclaracion, caratula_seleccionada, fecha, tiene_expediente, tipo_gravedad, id_distribuidora, id_tipocaratula

REGISTROS GUARDADOS:

252 ,"SEMANA 1 "    ,"Anomalías de Seguridad Pública MODERADA SEMANA 1 "    ,"2023-10-22 21:00:00"  ,true   ,"MODERADA" ,1  ,2
253 "SEMANA 2 " ,"Denuncias de Seguridad Pública GRAVE SEMANA 2 "   ,"2023-10-22 21:00:00"  ,true   ,"GRAVE"    ,1  ,3
254 ,"SEMANA 3 "    ,"Denuncias de Seguridad Pública GRAVE SEMANA 3 "   ,"2023-10-22 21:00:00"  ,true   ,"GRAVE"    ,2  ,3

En la Tabla de Expediente yo tengo estas columnas:

id  |   fecha |  nro_expediente |  id_caratula |  id_distribuidora

en la columna id_caratula (CALCULO QUE ESTÁ MAL PENSADA) : porque necesito que el usuario seleccione una de las caratulasSeleccionadas de las que se han guardado al momento de crear una caratula, y que se corresponda con la distribuidora tambien, que este mismo usuario ingresó al momento de cargar la carátula....

Entonces, necesitaría asignar una "variable" para caratulaSeleccionada y otra para distribuidora, para que estas variables estén en la tabla de Expediente también. Digo desde mi ignorancia, ya que mi frustración no me permite pensar una lógica para pensar como resolver este problema....

Mi tema es que el usuario tiene que ver una Tabla de Expediente en la cual va viendo los registros que va cargando, y en esta tabla podría ver
la fecha, nro_expediente, la caratulaSeleccionada que se ha seleccionado, y la distribuidora  a la que correspondia esa caratula....

[image: ESTE ES UN SCREEN DEL FORMULARIO DE EXPEDIENTE QUE NECESITO CARGAR (QUE NO FUNCIONA):]

[image: ESTE ES UN SCREEN DEL FORMULARIO DE CARATULA (QUE FUNCIONA)]

[image: ESTE ES UN SCREEN DE LO QUE SE GUARDA AL MOMENTO DE CARGAR UNA CARATULA, EN EL ATRIBUTO caratulaSeleccionada]

[image: ESTE ES UN SCREEN DE LO QUE LUEGO EL USUARIO TIENE QUE SELECCIONAR AL MOMENTO DE CREAR UN EXPEDIENTE, SELECCIONANDO EL TIPO DE CARATULA QUE NECESITE]

*ACLARACIÓN *
El Atributo caratulaSeleccionada es un String, que es el resultado de una CONCATENACIÓN de los atributos:

caratulaSeleccionada:  tipoCaratula  + tipoGravedad + aclaracion

ej:  "Anomalias de Seguridad Publica" + "GRAVE"  + "Semana 22"

caratulaSeleccionada: Anomalias de Seguridad Publica GRAVE Semana 22

CUANDO YO HAGO UN GET DESDE POSTMAN A ESTA URL :
http://localhost:8080/expediente_rest/

OBTENGO UN JSON DE ESTE FORMATO:

{
"id": 1,
"fecha": "2023-10-26T17:53:02.291+00:00",
"caratulaSeleccionada": {
"id": 253,
"fecha": "2023-10-23T00:00:00.000+00:00",
"tieneExpediente": true,
"aclaracion": "SEMANA 2 ",
"distribuidora": {
"id": 1,
"nombreDistribuidora": "EdERSA"
},
"tipoCaratula": {
"id": 3,
"tipoDeCaratula": "Denuncias de Seguridad Pública"
},
"tipoGravedad": "GRAVE",
"caratulaSeleccionada": "Denuncias de Seguridad Pública GRAVE SEMANA 2 "
},
"nroExpediente": 123456,
"distribuidora": {
"id": 1,
"nombreDistribuidora": "EdERSA"
}
}

ALGO ASÍ TENGO QUE PODER ENVIARLE EN MI FORMULARIO DE ANGULAR, DISCRIMINANDO ÚNICAMENTE A LOS ATRIBUTOS QUE ESPECIFICO EN MI CLASE DE EXPEDIENTE DE Spring-Boot llamada Expediente.Java

Comment: Puedes agregar el mensaje de error que te muestra o que tienes?

Comment: ​
error: Object { id: 352, fecha: "2023-10-26T03:00:00.000+00:00", nroExpediente: 46464, … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
​
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/expediente_rest/save: 400 OK"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 400
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "http://localhost:8080/expediente_rest/save"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
cargar-nuevo-expediente.component.ts

​

ESE Error me tira desde el Navegador. 

EN la Consola de Spring boot me larga este error:

Comment: En la consola de Spring boot me larga esto : 


..............
..................

:::::::::::
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.eprern.anomalias.model.nuevaCaratula.Expediente.caratulaSeleccionada -> com.eprern.anomalias.model.nuevaCaratula.Caratula